# match any part of a URL in lucene

Tags: lucene

Presently i am using PrefixQuery it's working fine but it get's a record like if my url is
http://xyz.com then it will get http://xyz.com and http://xyz.com/service/...
but it can't get http://www.xyz.com and http://xyz.co.in.i want to search based on any parts of url my code is :-

```
                    Term term = new Term("URL", siteUrl.toLowerCase());
        Query query1 = new PrefixQuery(term);
        booleanQuery.add(query1,BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `WildcardQuery`. But you need to know that it has bad performance, especially with queries with a leading wildcard (not because it has been poorly implemented but because of how Lucene internally stores its term dictionary).

Can't your use-case be solved by using a custom analyzer?